# Return view in controll using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have this ajax function that requests this route to login, but I want the redirection to be directly on the controller if the login is successful.

My ajax request:

```
$('#btn_login').on('click', function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var pass = $('#pass').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "login",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            name,
            pass
        },
        success: function (data) {                    },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Login Error ');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

My route.php:

Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@authenticate');

My LoginCOntrol.php:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'pass');

    $email = $credentials['email'];
    $password = $credentials['pass'];
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        return view('login.homepage')
    }else{
        return redirect()->back();  
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's your question? What keeps you from performing a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Try on ajax:

```
success: function (data) {location.href=data.url;},
```

And on Controller

Change

`return view('login.homepage')`

to

`return response()->json(['url'=>route('homepage')]);`

Hope this will answer your question.